# Consulta GET en appex

Tags: python, base-de-datos, oracle, get, apex

Tengo una duda en cuanto a una **petición get** que quiero realizar desde python a apex.

Mi codigo en oracle es el siguente:

```
BEGIN
   SELECT *
    FROM HABET_PBI_SALIENTES
    WHERE CALL_START BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(:p_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:p_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
END;
```

y la url que quiero utilizar es esta

> https:1.oraclecloudapps.com/xxx/GET_DATA_CLIENT_SALIENTES?p_start_date='2024-01-17'&p_end_date='2024-01-26'

pero me da un **status 555**, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error completo? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.